# Python cPickle from a db field TypeError

Tags: python, postgresql, unicode, typeerror, pickle

In my project i save a list as a cPickle object in a byte field of my postgresql db like this:

```
my_list = list(self.outhtml)
bitRst = cPickle.dumps(my_list)
cur.execute("INSERT INTO frontend_t_test (test_id, test_data, test_creation, ip_addr) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
                    (str(id(self)),
                     psycopg2.Binary(bitRst), dt, test_utils.return_ip()))
```

All done, when i try to retrive my list i do:

```
cur = myconn.cursor()

cur.execute("""SELECT test_data FROM frontend_t_test WHERE test_id = %s""",(idTest,))
res = cur.fetchall()
with open(res, 'rb') as f:
    mynewlist = cPickle.load(f)
```

but instead of the original list i get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       with open(res, 'rb') as f:
>   TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

How can i retreive my pickled list from db?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `pickle.load` method expects to get a file like object, but you are providing a list (`res`) instead. You need to write the result of `cur.fetchall` to a file and pass that in.

Answer (score 1):

The `pickle.load` method expects to get a file object, but you are providing a list (`res`) instead. You need to write the result of `cur.fetchall` to a file and pass that in or use `pickle.dump` to write the list:

```
with open('outfile', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(res, fp)
```

and for reading:

```
with open('outfile', 'rb') as f:
    mynewlist = pickle.load(res)
```

Comment: if i try to dump like you suggest i receive the response: raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle buffer objects

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: For this project 2.7.1

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to be a known bug that is resolved as a  'won't fix' for 2.7. http://bugs.python.org/issue8323

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to "open" data returned from cursor. Just use the data and call `loads`.

```
cur.execute("""SELECT test_data FROM frontend_t_test WHERE test_id = %s""",(idTest,))
res = cur.fetchone()
data = str(res[0])  # buffer => str
mynewlist = cPickle.loads(data)
```

Comment: TypeError: loads() argument 1 must be string, not buffer

Comment: data is <read-only buffer for 0x0000000003875370, size 1061, offset 0 at 0x0000000003965EA0>

Comment: Postgres' buffers! I just added str().